# How do i show suggessions in AutoCompleteTextView Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview, autosuggest

there

I have an problem like suggestions not showing automatically in AutoCompleteTextView,

#### So what is my flow?

1. I added an `com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`
2. initialize the variable in Kotlin using binding.
3. Set empty Adapter to `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`
4. now i implement an logic in `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`

   - If user input an word, after 1 second i hit an api for suggestions
   - i got success in fetching suggestions in API
   - where i got suggestions, there i notify MaterialAutoCompleteTextView `adapter`

#### Problem

```
- I did not show any suggestions in `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`
- but i fetch suggestions successfully
```

> If i remove one character or type one character then it show APIs suggestions properly

#### What is my requirement

- i need to show suggestions automatically when API fetch suggestions successfully
- do not wanna using

```kotlin
autoCompletetextView.text = autoCompletetextView.text.toString()
```

#### What i tried

- showDropDown()
- performCompletion()
- adapter.notifyDataSetChange()